# ForceMode.VelocityChange change is so dramatic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making a movement script, and here is the inside of the class:

```
// This is a reference to the Rigidbody component called "rb"
public Rigidbody rb;

public float forwardForce = 500f;
public float sidewaysForce = 0.01f;

// We marked this as "Fixed"Update because we 
// are using it to mess with physics.
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    // Add a forward force
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if ( Input.GetKey("d") ) 
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if ( Input.GetKey("a") ) 
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

The width of the rectangular plane the player is on is 15, and the player is in the center. But for some reason, when I press "a", the player zooms off the plane. This is happening on the other side as well.

Comment: 1. The player moves slower FORWARDS
2. The zooming off the plane is the same
I changed the speed to 250.

Answer (score 1):

[Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name.
As you are doing the `rb.AddForce` in the update, you might be doing it a very high frequency so the forces add up and make the movement abrupt.

Comment: "High Frequency"? As in you think I am holding down the key? Or rapidly pressing it?

Comment: As holding it. When you press it, it may seem its only once, but as it was for a while (even its a small amount of time), the code went into the `Input.GetKey` many times. Try [Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) instead

Comment: thats kind of strange though, because im following a brackeys tutorial, and it worked fine for him

Comment: maybe that is not the problem. Just one suggestion of what can the problem be :)

Comment: that does not explain why a value of 1 sends it so far

Comment: well what the heck. i changed the value of sidewaysForce within unity and forgot to change it back.